# Bootstrap grid break not working as expected

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some issue with the bootstrap grid system. [image]

As you can see in the second row, the box orientates on the previous element. this causes some not so nice looking behavior. how can i force the 4th element to orientate on the heighest element in the previous row?

```
<div class="row ">
                <div class="col-md-8" border="1">
                    <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col-md-12 f42_Col f42_MainWrapper" >
                            <button style="float:right;margin-top:10px;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </button>
                            <h5>test</h5>

                            <br></br>

                            <!-- gets repeated -->
                            <div class="f42_ModuleWrapper">                                 
                                <div class="f42_ConfigWrapper">

                                    <div class="f42_ConfigButtonWrapper">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        </button>

                                        <button style="margin:5px;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        </button> 
                                    </div>                                          

                                    <div class="f42_ArticleWrapper">
                                        112312111212123113 414141234235252345363636dfdffdfdg
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="f42_ArticleWrapper">
                                        112312111212123113 414141234235252345363636dfdffdfdg
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="f42_ArticleWrapper">
                                        112312111212123113 414141234235252345363636dfdffdfdg
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>  

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 f42_Col f42_MainWrapper">                              
                            <h5>test</h5>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4 f42_Col f42_MainWrapper" >
                            <h5>test test</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 f42_Col f42_MainWrapper">
                            <h5>TEBS</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div> 


.f42_MainWrapper{
        border-radius: 15px;
        border:white medium solid;
        background-color:#C4C4C4;
    }

    .f42_ModuleWrapper {
        float: left;
    }
    .f42_ConfigWrapper {
        display: table;
        margin:20px; 
        padding:5px; 
        width:1px; 
        height:1px;
        background-color:black;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .f42_ArticleWrapper{
        height:50px; 
        padding:4px;
        margin:4px; 
        width:200px; 
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color:white;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .f42_ConfigButtonWrapper{
        text-align: right;
    }
```

Comment: If you don't need a different number of columns per row on a smaller layout (e.g. two columns on `sm` instead of three on `md`), you can divide the screen into three columns and your boxes to the corresponding column (e.g. box four would be added to column one). If you do need a different number of columns create multiple layouts, duplicate the boxes, and hide / show a layout based on the viewport size (e.g. `hidden-xs`) or take a look at flexbox

Comment: it has to work for desktop only so the fix columns way should work for me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this as well. The two options I've come up with are:

- Setting the panels to a fixed height
- Using columns

The first approach is the easiest if you are willing to sacrifice fluid heights. This works for me 50% of the time and I do it when I can.

Using columns rather than rows (pinterest style) enables you to have fluid panels, but makes it harder to handle the order. Here is an example of the columns approach:

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <div class="f42_ModuleWrapper">                                 
        <div class="f42_ConfigWrapper">

          <div class="f42_ConfigButtonWrapper">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </button>

              <button style="margin:5px;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </button> 
          </div>                                          

          <div class="f42_ArticleWrapper">
              112312111212123113 414141234235252345363636dfdffdfdg
          </div>

          <div class="f42_ArticleWrapper">
              112312111212123113 414141234235252345363636dfdffdfdg
          </div>

        </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <div class="f42_ModuleWrapper">                                 
        <div class="f42_ConfigWrapper">

          <div class="f42_ConfigButtonWrapper">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </button>

              <button style="margin:5px;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </button> 
          </div>                                          

          <div class="f42_ArticleWrapper">
              112312111212123113 414141234235252345363636dfdffdfdg
          </div>

          <div class="f42_ArticleWrapper">
              112312111212123113 414141234235252345363636dfdffdfdg
          </div>

          <div class="f42_ArticleWrapper">
              112312111212123113 414141234235252345363636dfdffdfdg
          </div>


          <div class="f42_ArticleWrapper">
              112312111212123113 414141234235252345363636dfdffdfdg
          </div>

        </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <div class="f42_ModuleWrapper">                                 
        <div class="f42_ConfigWrapper">

          <div class="f42_ConfigButtonWrapper">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </button>

              <button style="margin:5px;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </button> 
          </div>                                          

          <div class="f42_ArticleWrapper">
              112312111212123113 414141234235252345363636dfdffdfdg
          </div>

          <div class="f42_ArticleWrapper">
              112312111212123113 414141234235252345363636dfdffdfdg
          </div>

          <div class="f42_ArticleWrapper">
              112312111212123113 414141234235252345363636dfdffdfdg
          </div>

        </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <div class="f42_ModuleWrapper">                                 
        <div class="f42_ConfigWrapper">

          <div class="f42_ConfigButtonWrapper">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </button>

              <button style="margin:5px;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </button> 
          </div>                                          

          <div class="f42_ArticleWrapper">
              112312111212123113 414141234235252345363636dfdffdfdg
          </div>

          <div class="f42_ArticleWrapper">
              112312111212123113 414141234235252345363636dfdffdfdg
          </div>

          <div class="f42_ArticleWrapper">
              112312111212123113 414141234235252345363636dfdffdfdg
          </div>

        </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Woah, but how would you do that when iterating over a list?

Comment: It depends on the language, but I most recently did this with PHP. The first step was using array_chunk() to break the data set into a collection of arrays. Then I iterated over the collection, creating a column for each one. Inserting the panels with JavaScript is another (probably more elegant) solution.

Comment: No, what I mean is, instead of defining all of the section manually, is it possible to specify once in a loop and use classes to determine which column that iteration should be apart of?

Comment: Oh, that sparked an idea for me. If you know it's going to be 3 columns wide, then maybe do 3 loops, then in each loop you can increment the counter by 3. So first loop would go 1, 4, 7, etc. Second loop would go 2, 5, 8, etc. Third loop would go 3, 6, 9, 12, etc.

Comment: That approach will be a bit better for maintaining your order.

Answer (score 0):

Reading ForrestLyman's answer sparked my idea for a fix to this problem (I have the same issue on my site).

If you know it's going to be 3 columns wide, then maybe do 3 loops, then in each loop you can increment the counter by 3. So first loop would go 1, 4, 7, etc. Second loop would go 2, 5, 8, etc. Third loop would go 3, 6, 9, 12, etc.

So, here's what you could do in code:

```
<div class="visible-xs">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
      <!-- Use two different loops here, going 1, 3, 5, 7, etc -->
      <!-- Second loop going 2, 4, 6, 8, etc -->
   </div>
</div>
<div class="visible-sm">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
      <!-- Use three different loops here, going 1, 4, 7, 10, etc -->
      <!-- Second loop going 2, 5, 8, 11, etc -->
      <!-- Third loop going 3, 6, 9, 12, etc -->
   </div>
</div>
<div class="visible-md">
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <!-- Use four different loops here, going 1, 5, 9, 13, etc -->
      <!-- Second loop going 2, 6, 10, 14, etc -->
      <!-- Third loop going 3, 7, 11, 15, etc -->
      <!-- Fourth loop going 4, 8, 12, 16, etc -->
   </div>
</div>
<div class="visible-lg">
   <div class="col-lg-2">
      <!-- Use six different loops here, going 1, 7, 13, 19, etc -->
      <!-- Second loop going 2, 8, 14, 20, etc -->
      <!-- Third loop going 3, 9, 15, 21, etc -->
      <!-- Fourth loop going 4, 10, 16, 22, etc -->
      <!-- Fifth loop going 5, 11, 17, 23, etc -->
      <!-- Sixth loop going 6, 12, 18, 24, etc -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i came up with a jquery answer that works quite well if you're up for it. demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/114/

This code finds the column of the lowest height and then appends the new section to that column.  It's run as a loop so as different sections of different heights are added the column, its rechecking the current heights of all the columns and comparing them to each other to find the shortest column to place the new content.  This way, you'll get the most even column lengths across all three columns despite the variable heights of the new content.  hope this helps!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var first = $('.first');
    var second = $('.second');
    var third = $('.third');

    $('.toBePlaced > .section').each(function () {
        var height = $(this).height();
        var lowest = first;
        if (first.height() < lowest.height()) { lowest = first; }
        if (second.height() < lowest.height()) { lowest = second; }
        if (third.height() < lowest.height()) { lowest = third; }

        $(this).appendTo(lowest);
    });
});

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-4 first">
        <div class="section">
            I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. 
        </div>
    </div> <!-- first -->
    <div class="col-xs-4 second">
        <div class="section">
            I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. 
        </div>
    </div> <!-- second -->
    <div class="col-xs-4 third">
        <div class="section">
            I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here.
        </div>
    </div> <!-- third -->
</div> <!-- container -->

<div class="toBePlaced col-xs-4">
    <div class="section">
        I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. I have content here. 
    </div>
</div>
```